# ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_176 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 128, 3]

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have been trying to use TensorFlow for image segmentation with U-Nets

Code:

```
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS))
s = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x / 255)(inputs)


c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(s)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c1)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c1)
p1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c1)
```

I have added a couple of more layers as well. But  I think the issue is in the inputs layer.

```
checkpointer = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('unet_test.h5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

callbacks = [
        tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=2, monitor='val_loss'),
        tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='logs')]

results = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_split=0.1, batch_size=16, epochs=25, callbacks=callbacks)
```

When I try to fit, this is the error:

```
Epoch 1/25
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 128, 128, 3) for input Tensor("input_23:0", shape=(None, 128, 128, 3), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 128, 3).

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-180608a30979> in <module>
      3 
      4 
----> 5 results = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_split=0.1, batch_size=16, epochs=25)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     64   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
     65     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
---> 66       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     67 
     68     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    846                 batch_size=batch_size):
    847               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
--> 848               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
    849               # Catch OutOfRangeError for Datasets of unknown size.
    850               # This blocks until the batch has finished executing.

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    578         xla_context.Exit()
    579     else:
--> 580       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    581 
    582     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    625       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    626       initializers = []
--> 627       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    628     finally:
    629       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    503     self._graph_deleter = FunctionDeleter(self._lifted_initializer_graph)
    504     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
--> 505         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    506             *args, **kwds))
    507 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2444       args, kwargs = None, None
   2445     with self._lock:
-> 2446       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2447     return graph_function
   2448 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   2775 
   2776       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 2777       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   2778       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   2779       return graph_function, args, kwargs

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   2655     arg_names = base_arg_names + missing_arg_names
   2656     graph_function = ConcreteFunction(
-> 2657         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
   2658             self._name,
   2659             self._python_function,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    979         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    980 
--> 981       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    982 
    983       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    439         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    440         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 441         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    442     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    443 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    966           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    967             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 968               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    969             else:
    970               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /home/gokul/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:571 train_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    /home/gokul/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /home/gokul/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /home/gokul/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/gokul/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:531 train_step  **
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    /home/gokul/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:927 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    /home/gokul/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py:717 call
        return self._run_internal_graph(
    /home/gokul/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py:888 _run_internal_graph
        output_tensors = layer(computed_tensors, **kwargs)
    /home/gokul/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:885 __call__
        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs,
    /home/gokul/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:176 assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError('Input ' + str(input_index) + ' of layer ' +

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d_176 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 128, 3]
```

This is the model summary:

```
Model: "model_5"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_23 (InputLayer)           [(None, 128, 128, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_22 (Lambda)              (None, 128, 128, 3)  0           input_23[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_176 (Conv2D)             (None, 128, 128, 16) 448         lambda_22[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_86 (Dropout)            (None, 128, 128, 16) 0           conv2d_176[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_177 (Conv2D)             (None, 128, 128, 16) 2320        dropout_86[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_46 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 64, 64, 16)   0           conv2d_177[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_178 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 32)   4640        max_pooling2d_46[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_87 (Dropout)            (None, 64, 64, 32)   0           conv2d_178[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_179 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 32)   9248        dropout_87[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_47 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 32, 32, 32)   0           conv2d_179[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_180 (Conv2D)             (None, 32, 32, 64)   18496       max_pooling2d_47[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_88 (Dropout)            (None, 32, 32, 64)   0           conv2d_180[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_181 (Conv2D)             (None, 32, 32, 64)   36928       dropout_88[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_48 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 16, 16, 64)   0           conv2d_181[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_182 (Conv2D)             (None, 16, 16, 128)  73856       max_pooling2d_48[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_89 (Dropout)            (None, 16, 16, 128)  0           conv2d_182[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_183 (Conv2D)             (None, 16, 16, 128)  147584      dropout_89[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_49 (MaxPooling2D) (None, 8, 8, 128)    0           conv2d_183[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_184 (Conv2D)             (None, 8, 8, 256)    295168      max_pooling2d_49[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_90 (Dropout)            (None, 8, 8, 256)    0           conv2d_184[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_185 (Conv2D)             (None, 8, 8, 256)    590080      dropout_90[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_22 (Conv2DTran (None, 16, 16, 128)  131200      conv2d_185[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_22 (Concatenate)    (None, 16, 16, 256)  0           conv2d_transpose_22[0][0]        
                                                                 conv2d_183[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_186 (Conv2D)             (None, 16, 16, 128)  295040      concatenate_22[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_91 (Dropout)            (None, 16, 16, 128)  0           conv2d_186[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_187 (Conv2D)             (None, 16, 16, 128)  147584      dropout_91[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_23 (Conv2DTran (None, 32, 32, 64)   32832       conv2d_187[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_23 (Concatenate)    (None, 32, 32, 128)  0           conv2d_transpose_23[0][0]        
                                                                 conv2d_181[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_188 (Conv2D)             (None, 32, 32, 64)   73792       concatenate_23[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_92 (Dropout)            (None, 32, 32, 64)   0           conv2d_188[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_189 (Conv2D)             (None, 32, 32, 64)   36928       dropout_92[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_24 (Conv2DTran (None, 64, 64, 32)   8224        conv2d_189[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_24 (Concatenate)    (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           conv2d_transpose_24[0][0]        
                                                                 conv2d_179[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_190 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 32)   18464       concatenate_24[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_93 (Dropout)            (None, 64, 64, 32)   0           conv2d_190[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_191 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 32)   9248        dropout_93[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_25 (Conv2DTran (None, 128, 128, 16) 2064        conv2d_191[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_25 (Concatenate)    (None, 128, 128, 32) 0           conv2d_transpose_25[0][0]        
                                                                 conv2d_177[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_192 (Conv2D)             (None, 128, 128, 16) 4624        concatenate_25[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_94 (Dropout)            (None, 128, 128, 16) 0           conv2d_192[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_193 (Conv2D)             (None, 128, 128, 16) 2320        dropout_94[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_194 (Conv2D)             (None, 128, 128, 1)  17          conv2d_193[0][0]                 
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,941,105
Trainable params: 1,941,105
```

Can anyone help me out here? Seems to be stuck at this for the past couple of hours  :(

Comment: Key error line is `WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 128, 128, 3) for input Tensor("input_23:0", shape=(None, 128, 128, 3), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 128, 3).`. Do you feed correct data to your network?

Comment: Yeah, I fed the right data to the network.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve your problem by now? The problem is for sure with your input data, from the error code you can see that the model is constructed for (128, 128, 3) images but you fed the network with data of (128, 3) dimensions. You can post your code here and maybe someone can help you.

Comment: @DominikFicek Thank you! you were right. I messed up the input layer :)